# Injectivity and surjectivity of $f\colon P(X) \times P(Y) \to P(X \times Y)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonempty sets and a function such as:

$$f: P(X) \times P(Y) \to P(X \times Y)$$
$$(A,B)\to A \times B$$

The question is if this function is injective or surjective, but I do not even understand the function. If $X={1,2,3}$ and $Y={1,2}$, $P(X)=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\},0\}$ and $P(Y)=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},0\}$, who is $f(\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\})$?

Comment: $f$ takes two sets $A$ and $B$ and returns the set of all pairs of elements in $A$ and $B$ (notice order).

Comment: Perhaps `P(X)` means the power set of set $X$?  It is worth saying so explicitly.  Also see [this introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: If it is the power set being discussed, the map $f$ is simply an inclusion mapping, i.e. if $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$, then $A\times B$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ (as @Sisyphus is saying above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to understand the function itself:

$f:\mathcal{P}(X)\times\mathcal{P}(Y)\to \mathcal{P}(X\times Y)~~~~~(A,B)\mapsto A\times B$

The function takes an ordered pair of sets, $(A,B)$ where $A$ is a subset of $X$ and $B$ is a subset of $Y$, and maps it to the set of all ordered pairs of the elements where the first element is in $A$ and the second is in $B$.

Your specific example, letting $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ we have

$f(\color{red}{\{1,2\}},\color{blue}{\{1,2,3\}}) = \{(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{1}),(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{2}),(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{3}),(\color{red}{2},\color{blue}{1}),(\color{red}{2},\color{blue}{2}),(\color{red}{2},\color{blue}{3})\}$

Similarly:

$f(\color{red}{\{2\}},\color{blue}{\{1,3\}})=\{(\color{red}{2},\color{blue}{1}),(\color{red}{2},\color{blue}{3})\}$

---

As for the question of injectivity, assuming that $X$ is nonempty and contains at least one element $x$:

$f(\emptyset,\emptyset)=\emptyset\times \emptyset=\emptyset$

also

$f(\{x\},\emptyset)=\{x\}\times\emptyset = \emptyset$

So, we have shown that there exist two inputs, $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ and $(\{x\},\emptyset)$ which both map to the same output, therefore so long as $X$ is nonempty the function will not be injective.  Reversing the roles of $X$ and $Y$ will show the same result for if $Y$ is nonempty.  We get as a result, $f$ is injective if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are simultaneously empty and is not injective otherwise.

---

As for the question of surjectivity.  You should know

$|\mathcal{P}(X)\times \mathcal{P}(Y)|=|\mathcal{P}(X)|\times|\mathcal{P}(Y)|=2^{|X|}\times 2^{|Y|}=2^{|X|+|Y|}$

and

$|\mathcal{P}(X\times Y)|=2^{|X\times Y|} = 2^{|X|\times |Y|}$

For large enough sets $X$ and $Y$, one has $2^{|X|+|Y|}<2^{|X|\times|Y|}$ which proves that $f$ cannot be surjective.  If $X$ and/or $Y$ are small enough however this isn't true and isn't sufficient to prove or disprove surjectivity.  For example if $X$ or $Y$ are empty, then the function will indeed be surjective.

For an explicit example, note that that with $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ there is no input which will map to $\{(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ despite this being an element of the codomain.  All of the outputs of the function will be "balanced" so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

$$f(\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}) = \{1,2\} \times \{1,2,3\} = \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)\}$$

Comment: This doesn't answer either whether $f$ is injective or subjective, and it is a bit too terse to help most Readers who are wondering (like the OP) how exactly $f$ is being defined.

Comment: @hardmath I take the question to be "who is f({1,2},{1,2,3})".

Comment: If that is your interpretation, then of course the answer is simply as you say.  However I expect that you can see that the function $f$ can be understood better if more than the single example is written out.

Comment: Then OP should have asked for more examples.

Comment: Here's what OP did write: "The question is if this function is injective or surjective, but I do not even understand the function."

Comment: So the main issue to be addressed is not the injectivity or surjectivity, but the function itself. That first, and then we can talk about injectivity or surjectivity.

Comment: Actually $f(\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\})$ is not defined in the OP's example since $Y=\{1,2\}$.  But perhaps the OP will accept your Answer.

Comment: Nice find.${} {}$